# If $X \in L_{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$, how can I show that $X \mathbf{1}_{B} \in L_{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

If $X \in L_{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$ then how can I show that: $X \mathbf{1}_{B} \in L_{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P).$

I am thinking of :

$||X\mathbf{1}_B||_{1}=(\int |X\mathbf{1}_B|^1 dP)^1)$

Where
$$\mathbf{1}_{B} = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if B $\in \Omega$} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What does the notation $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ mean?

Comment: @CameronWilliams a function space with continuous integrable functions

Comment: Just use that integrals preserve inequalities and that $|X1_B|\leq |X|$ and then integrate both sides

Comment: @AndrewShedlock how I can this.I do not know

Comment: As a side note, this question doesn't have to do with conditional expectations.

Comment: I will change the title though @parsiad thanks a lot.So I do not have to calculate the integral.I understand your thought and if I have fully understand is that the F is closed under unions since is sigma field right?So it will contain this product as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=X\boldsymbol{1}_{B}$.
We need to show that $Y$ is (*i*) measurable and (*ii*) integrable.

*Remark*.
One way to establish (*i*) is to show that indicator functions on members of $\mathcal{F}$ are measurable and so too are products of measurable functions.
Below, I opt for a direct approach instead.

*Proof of* (*i*).
Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel set.
If $A$ does not contain zero, then $Y^{-1}(A)=X^{-1}(A)$.
Otherwise, let $A^{\prime}=A\setminus\{0\}$ and note that
$$
Y^{-1}(A)=Y^{-1}(\{0\}\cup A^{\prime})=Y^{-1}(\{0\})\cup Y^{-1}(A^{\prime})=B^{c} \cup X^{-1}(\{0\}) \cup X^{-1}(A^\prime).
$$
In both cases, the final expression is a union of sets in $\mathcal{F}$, and hence the desired result follows by the closure of $\mathcal{F}$.

*Proof of* (*ii*).
Since $X$ is integrable,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X\boldsymbol{1}_{B}\right|\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X\right|\boldsymbol{1}_{B}\right]\leq\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X\right|\right]<\infty.
$$

Comment: why 0 must not be in $A$ ?

Comment: You misunderstand; it's just been broken up into two cases. In the first case, $A$ **does not** contain zero. In the second case, it **does**. In both cases, we find out that $Y^{-1}(A)$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: thank you @parsiad  and so from that occurred that $Y$ is measurable?

Comment: Yes, but it sounds like you might not be familiar with the definition of *measurable function*. You may want to take a step back and familiarize yourself with the definitions.

Comment: remind me (enlighten me).

Comment: under the closure of countable unions of F?

Comment: It's probably best you use a textbook. I recommend 
Chapters 1 and 2 of *Knowing the Odds: An Introduction to Probability* by John Walsh.